# On the post list, how do you show different text to the main content?

Tags: posts

Not sure if the title makes sense sorry, but at the moment on my blog there is a long list of posts (with the thumbnail custom field) - the text next to the thumbnail is just the first characters from within the post.

How exactly do I change that to something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Wow. nice people! Voting someone's first post down and not leaving a comment to explain anything. But you're right, let's have newcomers be frustrated and leave instantly. You can call yourself whatever you think is appropriate for such stuff. Voted up to zero again.

Comment: try to make it a better Q. Rethink if you can find the result on the "net" and proof that you tried. Show what you tried and give as lot of info as possible.

Comment: Please provide more information.  We don't know enough about your site, your theme, or what you're trying to accomplish to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt). You should be able to control that text by altering your Post's excerpts. You may need to click "Screen Options" at the top right of your Dashboard to have the Excerpt box be displayed when you create or edit posts. HTH.